# NTP client synchronizes with LOCAL instead of stratum 1

Tags: ntp, time-synchronization, ntpd

I have 2 NTP servers. One synchronized directly with a GPS clock (I will call this server 185), so st 0.
Then I have a second one (Let's call it 186) that should synchronize with the 185 since it is st 1 but instead it synchronizes with LOCAL.

```
[root@185 ~]# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*GENERIC(3)      .GPS.           0 l    6   64    7    0.000    5.902   2.454
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

```
[root@186 ~]# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 GENERIC(3)      .GPS.           0 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 192.168.61.185  .GPS.           1 u   52   64    1    0.238    0.036   0.000
*LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l   51   64    1    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Configuration is quite straight forward since this is one of the first tests we do. In addition, I have the parameter tinker panic 0 set in both ntp.conf.

Do you have any idea why 186 does not choose 185?

*Thanks in advance!*

***EDIT : To show that 186 can reach 185.***

***EDIT : more info (date is 1 Jan because the GPS is simulated) ***

```
[root@ntp1 ~]# ntpdate -d 192.168.xx.185
 1 Jan 10:08:16 ntpdate[17348]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Fri Dec 18 13:55:10 UTC 2020 (1)
Looking for host 192.168.xx.185 and service ntp
host found : 192.168.xx.185
transmit(192.168.xx.185)
receive(192.168.xx.185)
transmit(192.168.xx.185)
receive(192.168.xx.185)
transmit(192.168.xx.185)
receive(192.168.xx.185)
transmit(192.168.xx.185)
receive(192.168.xx.185)
server 192.168.xx.185, port 123
stratum 1, precision -23, leap 00, trust 000
refid [GPS], delay 0.02576, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    c39e6ff9.17cf49c0  Thu, Jan  1 2004 10:07:53.093
originate timestamp: c39e7011.1621002b  Thu, Jan  1 2004 10:08:17.086
transmit timestamp:  c39e7011.16146846  Thu, Jan  1 2004 10:08:17.086
filter delay:  0.02586  0.02576  0.02576  0.02583
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000067 0.000094 0.000098 0.000065
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02576, dispersion 0.00000
offset 0.000094
```

Comment: REACH is 0. That indicates that you can't reach that NTP server.

Comment: Actually it becomes 0 after a while, but after the restart reach isn't 0. `192.168.xx.185  LOCAL(0)        11 u   25   64    1    0.180    0.010   0.000`

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the output of `ntpdate -d 192.168.xx.185`. And stop redacting RFC1918-addresses. It just looks silly.

Comment: I do redact RFC1918-addresses because world is small, not for security issues... :)

Comment: Stop doing it anyway. It doesn't reveal anything about you.

Comment: Please include your ntpd configuration as well - using `grep '^[^#]' /etc/ntp.conf` is recommended to make it compact.

Comment: Also, as @vidarlo requested, please don't redact addresses.  It just makes it harder for others to help you.

Comment: And most importantly, please don't use the LOCAL driver.  It has been deprecated for many years.  Start with your distribution's default `/etc/ntp.conf` template (CentOS, Debian, & Ubuntu all have very sane defaults), and only change the things necessary for it to work in your environment.